# How to Pass dynamically create Powerpoint file to Google Cloud Storage in python

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to build a power-point in my python 2.7 application and upload it on the fly to Google Cloud Storage.

I can create the ppt, store on my local hard drive as an intermediate step and then pick up from there to upload to the Google cloud storage. This works well. However, my production application will run on Google App Server so I want to be able to create the powerpoint and upload to Google Storage directly (without the intermediate step).

Any ideas of how to do this? The blob.upload_from_file() seems to only be able to pickup files that are physically stored somewhere but as my app is building these powerpoints I don't know what to pass to the blob.upload_from_file as an argument? I tried to use StringIO module but its generating the error message below.

```
from google.cloud import storage
from pptx import Presentation
from StringIO import StringIO

prs = Presentation()
title_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[0]
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(title_slide_layout)
title = slide.shapes.title
subtitle = slide.placeholders[1]

title.text = "Hello, World!"
subtitle.text = "python-pptx was here!"

out_file = StringIO()
prs.save(out_file)

client = storage.Client()

bucket = client.get_bucket([GCP_Bucket_Name])

blob = bucket.blob('test.pptx')
blob.upload_from_file(out_file)
print blob2.public_url
```

> ValueError: Stream must be at beginning.

Answer (score 0):

You are uploading the `out_file` object, which is just an empty StringIO object.

Instead you have to:

1. Save the Presentation object to the file system `prs.save(savingPath)`
2. Read the object and put it in a StringIO object.
3. Finally upload the the StringIO object.

Here is the code:

```
from google.cloud import storage
from pptx import Presentation
from StringIO import StringIO

#Creates presentation
prs = Presentation()
title_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[0]
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(title_slide_layout)
title = slide.shapes.title
subtitle = slide.placeholders[1]

title.text = "Hello, World!"
subtitle.text = "python-pptx was here!"

prs.save('test.pptx')

client = storage.Client()

bucket = client.get_bucket('yourBucket')
blob = bucket.blob('test.pptx')

with open('test.pptx','r') as ppt:
    out_file = StringIO(ppt.read())

blob.upload_from_file(out_file)
print blob.public_url
```

Finally you mentioned the code will run on Google App Server, this product does not exist. If you meant Google App Engine keep in mind that not all the runtimes have [access to the file system](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/appengine-generation). So you might not be able to save the pptx file to the file system of the application.

Comment: Thanks. Your solution involves saving the file in an intermediate step and then picking up from that location and uploading to GCP. I'm trying to look for a workaround because as you correctly pointed out Google App Server will not let you save the file. So Im wondering if there is a way to pass the presentation directly during run time to Google Storage and avoid the prs.save('test.pptx') command which requires access to file system.

Comment: I strongly recommend you to use Python3 for your App Engine service. This way you would have read and write access to the /tmp directory and thus you would be able to temporary safe your pptx there. And anyway, Python 2.7 will not be maintained past 2020, it is time to move on!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by moving my GAE application from Standard to the Flexible environment in GAE. The flexible environment allows write to the preso file to the root directory and I pick it up from there, upload to Google storage and then delete the file in the root. This worked for me.